# selecting and highlighting text in javafx with events and identification

Tags: select, events, javafx, text, highlight

I have to interact in javaFx with text and have no fitting "node" for this situation.

I have to select a displayed text by mouse. This selection has to be highlighted with a specific background-color. Each further selections have to have other background colors and some selections have to have the same background-color. By click at the highlighted text, an event has to be activated/fired. It would be wonderful if there is also an contextmenue to interact with at right click on the marked text for removing the action and highlighting abilities. This text should be scrolled to by an other action event and at least to have a logical connection/reference/identification to a java object what is created with the content of the highlighted text. I have some external text filters, so I have to remember the position of the highlighted text.

Do you have any suggestions? Is there a right node for this in JavaFx? Any hidden library?

I am really frustrated because my actual solution with the webview element/webengine is very messy and some features are missing.

Actual solution:

```
Cycle1: Text => useFilter => constructHtmlReadyText => putIntoWebEngine => displayInWebViewer  
Cycle2: OnMouseReleased => getPositionOfTextAndText(by JavaScriptEngine) => addInformationOfPositionAndText => Cyclus1
```

The main problem on this scenario is to get the position of the selected text on the second selectioncycle.

Comment: Have a look at the third-party library [RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX)

Comment: With JavaFX 9+ you might be able to do this with a simple `Text` node, or even `TextFlow`. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57454184/6395627. But using _RichTextFX_ means you don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: @Slaw thx for your approach, but it is not possible to select a text by mouse at the `Text` or `TextFlow` node like in the `Textarea`. I didn't found any way to do that.

Comment: @James_D I tried your approach with `InlineCssTextArea` and I think I am on the right way. THX A LOT!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The example I linked shows you how to _indicate_ the text is selected. Actually selecting the text simply involves adding mouse listeners to the `Text` or `TextFlow` and using the API of `Text` / `TextFlow` to [determine where you "hit" in relation to the characters](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#hitTest(javafx.geometry.Point2D)). But as you've found out how to do it with _RichTextFX_ I suggest staying on that course. By the way, `TextArea` uses a `Text` node under-the-hood.